# R: Join and merge two data.frames

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe

I have two sample data.frames `df1`

```
df1 <-  structure(list(dataName = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("HA", "Kol"), class = "factor"), Site = structure(1:2, .Label = c("CA35", "df3"), class = "factor"), add = c(1L, 0L), proxy = c(23.5, 17.3)), .Names = c("dataName", "Site", "add", "proxy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

 df1
  dataName Site add proxy
1      Kol CA35   1  23.5
2       HA  df3   0  17.3
```

and `df2`

```
df2 <- structure(list(dataName = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("hcd", "Kol", "la"), class = "factor"), Site = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CA35", "holz", "leta"), class = "factor"), all = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("dummy", "ole", "Test"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("dataName", "Site", "all"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2
  dataName Site   all
1      Kol CA35  Test
2      hcd leta   ole
3       la holz dummy
```

What I am trying is to merge the data.frames using a join so that the end result would look like this:

```
df_new
  dataName Site add proxy   all
1      Kol CA35   1  23.5  Test
2       HA  df3   0  17.3  <NA>
3      hcd leta  NA    NA   ole
4       la holz  NA    NA dummy
```

I tried all the variations from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) post but I wasn't able to reach the desired end result using the `merge()` function. In my real data the data.frames are much bigger and contain more columns that one data.frame has and the other one doesn't. How could I solve this?

Comment: Did you try `merge(df1, df2, by=c("dataName", "Site"), all=T)`?

Answer (score 1):

This, I believe, will give you want you want, using only base `merge`.

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("dataName","Site"),all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)


df3
  dataName Site add proxy   all
1       HA  df3   0  17.3  <NA>
2      Kol CA35   1  23.5  Test
3      hcd leta  NA    NA   ole
4       la holz  NA    NA dummy
```

Note that because you have imbalanced columns and want to keep them, you have to specify that all = true.

Answer (score 0):

> df <- merge(df1, df2, by = c('dataName', 'Site'), all = T)